# what's the best strategy when pushing branches remotely when someone else already changed the same file

Tags: git, github

Let's say me and other colleague Tom both works on a project that has repository on github, John is the team leader who has control to merge pushed branches to master branch.I have my local branch A and modify a file "hello.cs", and Tom has his local branch B.

So after the commit, I push my branch A to remote repository, but I am not aware of that Tom had modified the "hello.cs" before and already pushed his branch to remote and merged by John. So it is very easy for John to merge my branch into master and overwrite the "hello.cs" on master branch(given by the fact that "hello.cs" is just one of 20 files changed).

So here is my question, before I push my branch, should I do a `git pull`, then rebase my branch on the new master branch(if there are new commits on it) and resolve conflicts. Is this `git pull`+ `git rebase` strategy the standard way to push changes remotely?

Comment: If there's any changes conflicting that can't be automatically merged Git will inform you as ask you do choose the changes to keep

Comment: "So it is very easy for John to merge my branch into master and overwrite the "hello.cs" on master branch" No, no, no, no. "Overwrite" is not something git.

Comment: Git *already* handles all those situations. If you push and you are out out of date, it will stop you *because you're out of date*. If you've modified a file locally that was modified remotely, it would stop you with a merge conflict. You *can* go around these safeguards but it's certainly not *easy* to do it by default. Do you *only* ever use `git push --force`? If so - stop and you'd stop having these problems. The other part is to make sure that people who use Git, you know *use Git* and don't try to go around it.

Comment: Where did you get this idea that merge and overwrite mean the same thing?  Hunt down everything you learned from there and kill it with fire, and then simply and completely ostracize that source. Anyplace telling you that has no least clue about Git (or any vcs).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Good news and bad news

You literally *cannot* overwrite a committed file.  The reason for this is simple: Git does not store *files.*  Git stores *commits*.

Now, it's true that commits store files.  The way this works is that you *pick some commit to check out*, and Git then *extracts all the files that are contained in that commit*.  This glosses over a lot of details, but it's critical to know that the commit stores the *entire snapshot*, of *all the files*, in a special Git-only format that only Git can use.  It has to be extracted first, in order to use it.

No part of *any* commit can ever be changed.  Either you have the commit, and then you have *all* of the files; or you don't have the commit, and therefore you have *none* of the files.

What you can do, using `git push --force`, is convince another Git repository to *discard commits*.  When you do, *all of the files in that commit are gone.*  You have not overwritten a file.  You *have* **deleted *all* the files in that commit**, by *deleting* that commit.  (Again, this glosses over a lot of details: sometimes you can un-delete.)

Any commits the other Git still has, still have all of *their* files.  Every commit has a full snapshot of all of its files!  But the commit you told them to throw away, they threw away.  They have *none* of *those* files.

It's easy to avoid this fate: *do not use `git push --force`* unless you know exactly what you are doing.  (Once you do know what you are doing, you may prefer `git push --force-with-lease`.)

#### The thing to do is to merge or rebase

You mention merging.  Merge does not mean *replace my files with his files*.  Merging means *combine my changes with his changes.*  But commits don't *store* changes.  They store snapshots.  So how can this work?

The key to understanding this is to realize that while commits do store files—in a special, read-only, Git-only, frozen format, which is why the commit has to be *extracted* before you can work on it—that's not all they store.  Each commit also stores some metadata.  This shows up with `git log`, for instance: who made the commit, when, and why (their log message).  In this metadata, each commit records its *previous* or *parent* commit.

If you take two commits in a row and compare their snapshots, the *difference* between the two snapshots tells you what changed.  That is, if we draw out a chain of commits:

```
... <-F <-G <-H
```

where the *latest* commit is the one with hash ID `H`—`H` stands in for the actual Git hash ID, which is too big and ugly to remember or repeat—then commit `H` itself contains, in its metadata, the actual hash ID of some earlier commit we'll just call `G`.  That is, `H` *points to* `G`.  Commit `G` stores the hash ID of its parent `F`: `G` points to `F`.

A branch name, in Git, is just a label holding the hash ID of the *latest* commit.  If commit `H` is the latest commit in `master`, for instance, we have:

```
...--F--G--H   <-- master
```

where I've gotten too lazy to draw the arrows between the commits themselves.  (All parts of any commit are frozen in time forever, including the backwards-pointing arrows between commits.  So if we just remember that they point backwards, it's not too terrible to just draw them without the arrow parts.)

Making a new commit on a branch is just a matter of having Git write out the new snapshot, add the metadata, and acquire a hash ID.  Git sets the new commit to point back to whichever commit you *had* out a moment ago.  Then Git writes the new commit's hash ID, whatever that is, into the *branch name*.  So now the name points to the latest commit.

You can have more than one branch name pointing to some commit!  This just means that all the commits are on *both* branches.  For instance, if we start with:

...--G--H   <-- master

and create the new name `branch` pointing to existing commit `H`, we get:

```
...--G--H   <-- master, branch
```

Now we need to know which *branch name* we're using.  We can attach the special name `HEAD` to one of the branch names, like this

```
...--G--H   <-- master, branch (HEAD)
```

to signal that we're on branch `branch`, not `master`.  The *current commit* is still commit `H`, so the files we will work with are those from commit `H`.

To make a new commit `I`, we have Git save a new snapshot, set its *parent* to the current commit `H`, and then write whatever hash ID new commit `I` gets into the current branch name:

```
          I   <-- branch (HEAD)
         /
...--G--H   <-- master
```

This means branch name values change over time, as the branch grows.  The arrow coming out of a branch name *moves*, which we can draw by moving the entire name-and-arrow, as above.

The commits themselves, once made, are frozen for all time.  At most, we can move a branch-name-and-arrow so that the name *doesn't* point to the commit any more.  For instance, suppose we move the name `branch` so that it points to `H` again:

```
          I   ???
         /
...--G--H   <-- branch (HEAD), master
```

Git *finds* commits using names—these names `branch` and `master`, for instance—and then working backwards.  Since no *name* finds `I`, commit `I` is now "lost".  If you remember its raw hash ID, *you* can find it, but *Git* won't find it on its own.  All of its files—its entire snapshot—are gone now; to "undelete" `I`, you need to know its hash ID.

(This is, in large part, what `git reset` is about: it moves branch names.  You can make it move a branch name and thereby "delete" a bunch of commits.)

Since a commit remembers its parent, we can also have Git *compare* the snapshots very easily.  This is what `git log -p` or `git show` does: you pick some commit to view, and Git looks at its parent commit too.  Git extracts *both* snapshots, parent and child, and compares them.  For files that are the same, Git says nothing.  For files that are different, Git shows you a recipe that will change the first commit into the second one.

#### Distributed development

Suppose you have:

```
          I--J   <-- yourbranch (HEAD)
         /
...--G--H   <-- master, origin/master
```

This `origin/master` is your Git remembering the `master` from another Git repository.  You've made a couple of new commits on your branch.  Meanwhile:

> ... Tom had modified the "hello.cs" before and already pushed his branch to remote and merged by John.

Let's take a look at what really happened in Tom's repository.  He made his own branch name, or used his own `master`.  (It doesn't really matter which one he did.  Tom's branch names are *Tom's*, and you won't ever see them—you're using *John's* as your `origin/master`.  John has *John's* repository, with *John's* branch names.)  Let's say Tom used a branch named `tom`, to help keep clear which Git we're looking at.

Tom did:

```
git checkout -b tom
```

to get:

```
...--G--H   <-- master, tom (HEAD), origin/master
```

Then, Tom made some commit(s), in which he modified some files.  Each of these new commits that Tom made have full and complete snapshots of his modified files:

```
...--G--H   <-- master, origin/master
         \
          K--L   <-- tom (HEAD)
```

(Your commits will be, or already are `I-J`, in our drawings, so we've named Tom's `K-L` here.)  Tom then sent his commits to John, using `git push`.

#### John's actions

Now, at this point it's helpful to know that *all Git repositories number commits the same way*.  So the hash IDs of commits `K-L` in *John's* repository match those of `K-L` in Tom's.  The *name* that identifies commit `L`, so that John's Git can work backwards, is whatever name Tom said to use–probably not `master`; possibly `tom` again, but let's use `pr/123` to call it a "pull request".  So John now has:

```
...--G--H   <-- master (HEAD)
         \
          K--L   <-- pr/123
```

Note that John doesn't have an `origin/master`, and his `master` *is* his current branch.  He now merges commit `L`.

John has an option.  He may force his Git to make a real merge rather than using Git's "fast-forward" option, so that he has this:

```
...--G--H------M   <-- master (HEAD)
         \    /
          K--L   <-- pr/123
```

Merge commit `M` has its own snapshot of *all* files, including any changes to `hello.cs`.  In this particular case, John's commit `M` has a `hello.cs` that probably matches the `hello.cs` in commit `L`.  What makes `M` a *merge commit* is that it has not just one but *two* parents.  Commit `M` points backwards to both `H` *and* `L`.

Or, he might allow his Git to use a "fast-forward" instead of a real merge.  Let's say he does this.  In that case, his repository now looks like this:

```
...--G--H--K--L   <-- master (HEAD), pr/123
```

Merge commit `M` does not exist this time: his repository just uses existing commit `L`.

In both cases, John can now delete his name `pr/123`: it's no longer needed.

#### Back to your repository

Right now, you still just have this:

```
          I--J   <-- yourbranch (HEAD)
         /
...--G--H   <-- master, origin/master
```

You must now get *new* commits from John.  To do that, you need the `git fetch` command.  You run `git fetch origin` and your Git obtains John's commits:

```
          I--J   <-- yourbranch (HEAD)
         /
...--G--H   <-- master
         \
          K--L   origin/master
```

This is where `git merge` comes in.

You *could* send commit `J` to John now, perhaps having him set *his* name `secondimage` or maybe `yourbranch`.  He would then have to figure out how to merge or rebase your work.  Or, you can do the merge or rebase yourself.

The goal of `git merge` is to *combine* work.  You have some changes you made in commit `I`, which you can view by comparing the snapshot in `H` to the snapshot in `I`.  You have some changes you made in commit `J`, which you can view by comparing the snapshot in `I` to that in `J`.  To view all your changes at once, you can compare the snapshot in `H` to that in `J`.

Meanwhile, Tom has some changes he made, which you can view one step at a time: compare `H` to `K`, then `K` to `L`; or just compare `H` to `L` directly, to see *all* of the changes Tom made.

Running:

```
git merge origin/master
```

tells your Git: *find the best common, shared commit*.<sup>1</sup>  That's commit `H`, obviously: commit `H` is on `master`, but also on `yourbranch` because `J` leads back to `I` which leads back to `H`.  Similarly, starting at `L`, we go back to `K` and then `H`.  So `H` is *shared*, and going any further back would just be silly, so it's the *best* shared commit too.

Having founds this shared, common commit—which Git calls the *merge base* of the two tip commits `J` and `L`—Git now compares the snapshots in `H` vs `J`, and again in `H` vs `L`:

```
git diff --find-renames <hash-of-H> <hash-of-J>   # what we changed
git diff --find-renames <hash-of-H> <hash-of-L>   # what they changed
```

Git's merge engine now *combines* these changes, file-by-file.  If Tom changed `hello.cs`, and you also changed `hello.cs`, Git *combines* the two changes as shown by the two diff listings.<sup>2</sup>

If all goes well, Git writes the resulting combined `hello.cs` file to two places: your work-tree, which contains the ordinary file you can see and work with, and Git's internal *index* aka *staging area*, which is where Git keeps the file copy that it will commit.<sup>3</sup>

If all goes well with this combining process—if Git is able to combine the changes, and apply the combined changes to the snapshot taken from commit `H`—Git will make a new *merge commit* `M`:

```
          I--J
         /    \
...--G--H      M   <-- yourbranch (HEAD)
         \    /
          K--L   origin/master
```

(There's still a `master` in your own Git, pointing to commit `H`, but it's too hard to draw now, so I left it out this time.)

You can now use `git push` to send your successfully-merged `M` commit, plus commits `I` and `J`, to John's repository, giving it some name.  Perhaps you'll call it something other than `yourbranch`; presumably you won't attempt to call it `master`, as John himself is the only one who should be updating John's `master`.  To call it `yourbranch`, you can just run:

```
git push origin yourbranch
```

(and you might want `git push -u` so that your Git now sets `origin/yourbranch` as the *upstream* of your branch named `yourbranch`).

---

<sup>1</sup>Note that while `origin/master` is technically not a *branch name*—it's a *remote-tracking name* instead—it functions like a branch name here, where we're really interested in *commits*, not branches.  Git isn't so much about *branches* after all.  It's about *commits*.  It's just that we *find* the commits by branch names or other names.  In this case, we're finding the commits by *remote-tracking names* like `origin/master`, too.

<sup>2</sup>Git does all of this internally, without having to run `git diff` directly.  The effect is *as if* Git ran `git diff` and read the diff listings, though.

3Technically, the index holds a *reference* to an internal Git *blob object*, rather than a copy of the file itself.  You can, however, think of this as the index / staging-area holding copies of each of the files taken from each commit.

During merging, the index expands: instead of holding *one* to-be-committed `hello.cs` file, originally from the *current* commit, it holds *three* `hello.cs` files, one from the merge base `H`, one from the current commit `J`, and one from their commit `L`.  If Git is able to combine their changes with your changes, Git will shrink this one entry back down to a to-be-committed combined copy, matching the updated work-tree copy.  If not, Git will leave the extra copies in the index, which is how Git knows that there is a merge conflict.  It will also leave a messy partial merge in your work-tree `hello.cs` file.

---

#### Rebasing is another option

Instead of merging—turning:

```
          I--J   <-- yourbranch (HEAD)
         /
...--G--H   <-- master
         \
          K--L   origin/master
```

into what we saw above—you can, if you like, *copy* your commits `I-J` to new and improved commits.  They will be *like* `I` and `J`, but:

- The copy of `I`, which we'll call `I'` to mark it as a copy, will start with the files that are in `L` before we make `I'`.
- `I'` will do *to* those files what `I` did to the files in `H`.
- The *parent* of `I'` will be `L`, not `H`.
- The copy of `J`, which we'll call `J'`, will likewise have `I'` as its parent and make the same changes to `I'`'s snapshot that `J` made to `I`'s.

So we'll draw this new-and-improved series of commits like this:

```
          I--J   <-- yourbranch-old
         /
...--G--H   <-- master
         \
          K--L   origin/master
              \
               I'-J'  <-- yourbranch-new (HEAD)
```

We *could* do this by creating the new branch name pointing to commit `L`, then copying each commit—`I` and `J`—one at a time.  The Git command that copies a commit like this is `git cherry-pick`.

There's a power tool, though, that will do all the work for us.  That power tool is `git rebase`.  This:

- lists out some set of commits to copy;
- does a `git checkout` of some commit where the copies should go;
- copies each commit, one at a time;
- and last, *moves* a branch name.

The branch name `git rebase` moves is the *current* branch name.  The commits it copies are the commits that are on the current branch, minus any commits that are *shared with* the place you say to copy the commits after.

In this case, we'd run:

```
git checkout yourbranch   # if needed
git rebase origin/master
```

Since `origin/master` names commit `L`, we'll copy commits that *are* on `yourbranch` but *aren't* on `origin/master`.  We *won't* copy `L`, nor `K`, nor `H`, nor anything before `H`.  We weren't going to copy `L` or `K` anyway, but that's OK!  This leaves only `J` and `I`.  Rebase knows to copy them in the right order—backwards for Git, but forwards for humans: `I` first, and then `J`.  So Git copies them, one at a time.

Then the `rebase` command, having made the copies, takes the branch name, `yourbranch`, and forces it to point to the last copied commit:

```
          I--J   [abandoned]
         /
...--G--H   <-- master
         \
          K--L   origin/master
              \
               I'-J'  <-- yourbranch (HEAD)
```

Since we *find* commits by starting from branch names and working backwards—that's what `git log` does—if we look now, it will look like we somehow *changed* commits `I` and `J` into `I'` and `J'`.  We didn't.  That's impossible.  Not even Git can change these commits.

But it *looks like* we changed the commits, as long as we don't pay any attention to the actual hash IDs.  As long as we've never sent the actual commits `I-J` themselves to some other Git repository, nobody will ever even know that we did this.

Having done this rebase, we can now `git push origin yourbranch`, exactly as before.  (You may want `git push -u`, as before.)

#### Rebase has a glitch of sorts

If "John" here represents a shared repository with some kind of branch access control—such as a GitHub repository—and you `git push` your own branches and then post GitHub-style *pull requests*, you may need to update your own PRs from time to time.

When you use rebase, as we saw above, this *copies* your commits the new and improved commits.  Having made the copies, you may need to update your GitHub PR.

Your GitHub PR consists of a name over in the GitHub repository.  It's not really a branch name, but it always functions *like* one, and always involves a branch name *somewhere*, maybe in a GitHub fork.  In either case, the branch name—whether it's in the main GitHub repository or a fork—*is* a branch name.  In this particular example, it's the name `yourbranch`.

Having updated your own Git repository:

```
...--K--L   <-- origin/master
         \
          I'-J'   <-- yourbranch (HEAD)
```

and run `git push -u origin yourbranch`, GitHub will set their name `yourbranch`, and you'll gain an `origin/yourbranch` in *your* Git repository:

```
...--K--L   <-- origin/master
         \
          I'-J'   <-- yourbranch (HEAD), origin/yourbranch
```

If there's some delay, though, perhaps `origin/master` will add a new commit `N` before your branch can be merged (with real or fast-forward merging), giving:

```
...--K--L--N   <-- origin/master
         \
          I'-J'   <-- yourbranch (HEAD), origin/yourbranch
```

You now need to re-rebase, producing:

```
             I"-J"   <-- yourbranch (HEAD)
            /
...--K--L--N   <-- origin/master
         \
          I'-J'   <-- origin/yourbranch
```

*They* now have your old commits `I'-J'`.*  You must tell them *discard those commits, replace them with my new and improved ones.*  This requires a form of force-push, e.g.:

```
git push -f origin yourbranch
```

If someone else has started to use your `I'-J'` sequence, this is not very friendly.

You can ensure that they only forget your `I'-J'` as recorded by *their* name `yourbranch` using `git push --force-with-lease`.  This has your Git check with their Git that their `yourbranch` still points to `J'` before having them update their `yourbranch` name to the updated `J"` copy.  This is generally a good idea—but it doesn't stop someone else from having depended on your `I'-J'` commit sequence.  The only real cure is to have an agreement in advance with all other users of the other Git that `yourbranch` can move in this way.

#### About `git pull`

The `git pull` command is really just a convenience.  To work with other people's commits, you must:

- use `git fetch` to *get* them
- use another, second Git command—`git merge` or `git rebase`—to *incorporate* them

and `git pull` does exactly that: run `git fetch`, then *immediately* run a second Git command, without giving you a chance to see what `git fetch` did.  You must choose that second Git command in advance, unaware of whether rebase, merge, or something else entirely might be your best course of action.

I generally *avoid* `git pull` because I like to fetch, then *see what happened*, and only then choose my next Git command.  I admit, however, that my preference is influenced by ancient Git's habit of having `git pull` wreck everything now and then.  (There were some very bad bugs in it, more than a decade ago, and I got burned more than once.)

#### Conclusions

- Know how commits work.  They hold full snapshots of all committed files, plus metadata.  There are a lot of subtleties here, none of which we covered above, about commits being made from what's in Git's *index* aka *staging area*.
- Know what `git merge` does.  It *does not* overwrite.  Know that the command-line `git merge` command will sometimes do a *fast-forward* operation, which is not an actual merge.  GitHub's green "merge" button (when used in merge mode; the dropdown on it lets you pick other modes) always does a real merge, though.
- Know what `git rebase` does, and when (and whether) to use it.
- Try not to use `git push --force`, even in its safer `--force-with-lease` variety.  If you don't ever rebase, you won't need to.  (Remember that GitHub's "rebase and merge" mode, for its green merge button dropdown, forces a rebase!  It then does a fast-forward to the rebased commits.  It would be nice if there were a fast-forward option that didn't rebase.)
- If you must force-push, make sure *all users of the other Git repository* have agreed in advance that branch names will be force-pushed.  They must understand which names and which commits they can depend on, and which ones might get yanked around due to rebasing.

Answer (score 0):

In general, the actions of developers to push some changes depend on the adopted git-strategy in the team.
Most likely, there is main branch (master, develop and etc) on github repository. Every time before pushing your branch it's recommended to rebase all changes from main branch to local branch and resolve conflict in local branch. Than push local branch to github repository.
So, `git pull` + `git rebase` + `git push` may be good way.

Read about git strategy [Gitflow Workflow](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/comparing-workflows/gitflow-workflow)!